# Android Webview programmatically change the orientation of the displayed webpage

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview and I want to be able to change the orientation of the displayed page programmtically. 
I prevent my activity from being recreated again when the user changes the orientation of the phone by setting this in my Manifest file.

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

However on one of my tabs I want to programmatically change the orientation of the webpage when the user changes it as well. So I want to listen to the changes in the phone orienatation and change that of the page view accordingly. Currently when the phone's orientation is changed to landscape the webpage still shows in portrait.

Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have edited the question with more details @RaghavSood

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate only the WebView and nothing else, create a custom WebView like this:

```
public class VerticalWebView extends WebView {
    final boolean topDown = true;

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

(Change `topDown` to false if you want to rotate the other way)

Now simply use it in your XML as follows:

```
<com.my.package.VerticalWebView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</com.my.package.VerticalWebView>
```

Keep in mind that this just rotates the View shown on the screen, and any links etc. will fail to work as it does not remap touch coordinates to the new location of the corresponding point.

Comment: I want to be able to change the rotation at runtime. What you have provided sets its once and for all.

Comment: Raghav ...how do you get the XML to work like that, i keep getting inflate exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you want to change to landscape/portrait. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)

Comment: The problem here is that the device stops listening to orientation changes once you use the `setRequestedOrientation()` method. He wants to listen for those changes and change his webview accordingly.